# Jung graph library: how to search vertices based on vertex property?

Tags: java, graph, vertex, jung, edges

I am working with Jung framework to maintain and visualize my directed graph. My vertex and edge are custom classes. In the vertex class I maintain a set of vertex properties like, tag, state, etc.

I need to search the graph for vertex with specific property. For example, if a tag is given, i need to search the graph to find the vertex that hold that tag. I am not sure how to do it efficiently.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUNG does not, itself, maintain indexes of your vertex tags, because it doesn't know anything about them.  You will need to construct and maintain your own indexes (e.g., a Map from tag values to a set of vertices).

Note that this is not a JUNG-specific question at all, really.

Comment: Well, may be I was not clear. I know that Jung doesn't have any info about my custom class. However, my question was very jung specific. Is there any built-in support in Jung, to traverse a jung graph (DFS/BFS)from root node (if I specify one). I need to traverse the graph to check the node tag and update the node status (which is not jung specific). OR, do I have to implement the traversal code? Hope this is clear now.

Comment: Why traverse the graph?  You can just iterate over the vertices.  Or, as I said, maintain an index of vertex properties.  The only reason to traverse the graph would be if the update had some dependence on the topology.